# Get posts of a thread and 0 or 1 if the user asking liked the post

Tags: mysql, sql

one more time I turn to you for asking about mysql, definitely not my best skill. In fact, seems not to be very complex. This is my simplified scenario, I have two tables, one for posts, another for likes to posts:

### **Table post_forum structure**

```
id     thread    post   likes   user_id    created
```

### **Table likes_to_post structure**

```
id     post_id   user_id   created
```

This is my query for obtain posts from $start to $next for a thread $thread_id:

```
 $query = "SELECT 
                post_forum.id,
                post_forum.user_id,
                post_forum.post, 
                post_forum.likes,
                post_forum.created 
            FROM post_forum 
            WHERE post_forum.thread ='{$thread_id}' 
            ORDER BY post_forum.id DESC LIMIT $start,$next";
```

What I want to do is get por every post, a `0` or `1` value for a field saying if the user `$user_id` has liked every post, being `$user_id` the id of user that asks the post, in one query if possible. 
Thanks a lot in advance, any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$query = "SELECT 
            a.id,
            a.user_id,
            a.post, 
            a.likes,
            a.created,
            IF(b.user_id IS NOT NULL,1,0)
        FROM post_forum a
        LEFT JOIN likes_to_post b
            ON b.user_id=$user_id AND a.id = b.post_id
        WHERE a.thread ='{$thread_id}' 
        ORDER BY a.id DESC LIMIT $start,$next";
```

This is the query: it returns `1` if liked and `0` if no:
However you should use [mysqli](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) or [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) to prevent security attacks

**EDIT**
Mysqli example(I'm not sure about thread_id, I suppose it's a number):

```
$query = "SELECT 
        a.id,
        a.user_id,
        a.post, 
        a.likes,
        a.created,
        IF(b.user_id IS NOT NULL,1,0)
    FROM post_forum a
    LEFT JOIN likes_to_post b
        ON b.user_id=? AND a.id=b.post_id
    WHERE a.thread ='{?}' 
    ORDER BY a.id DESC LIMIT ?,?";
//Connect to datatabase
$mysqli = new mysqli($Hostname, $Username, $Password, $DatabaseName);
$stmt = $mysqli->stmt_init();
$stmt->prepare($query);
    $stmt->bind_param('iiii', $user_id,$thread_id,$start,$next)
        $stmt->execute()
            $stmt->store_result();
            $result = $stmt->bind_result($id, $user_id, $post, $likes, $created,$liked);
            if($stmt->num_rows>0){
                while (mysqli_stmt_fetch($stmt)) {
                    [Do something]
                }
            }
```

Comment: seems there's some missing, I added ON b.user_id=$user_id AND a.id = b.post_id and worked perfectly :)

Answer (score 2):

You would need a query like this:

```
SELECT p.id, CASE WHEN l.id IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE 1
FROM post_forum p
LEFT JOIN likes_to_post l
  ON l.post_id = p.id
  AND l.user_id = ?
```

This does assume you're using PDO with parameterized queries. The query takes the user id as its only parameter.